# Which of the creatures involved can continue its turn right after a reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, reactions

I have some uncertainty about **reactions** in the 5e PHB.

The book (page 190) reads:

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start
>   of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature’s turn,
>   that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.

Which creature can continue its turn right after the reaction — the one that causes the interruption, or the creature that was interrupted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The creature that was interrupted. A Reaction is an "action" taken when it's not your turn, so you don't have a turn to continue.

Example:
Fighter and Goblin are adjacent to one another. 
Fighter swings and misses (Action) and elects to stay where he is (no Move), then ends his turn. 
Goblin swings and misses (Action), then tries to get away (Move), triggering the Fighter's Opportunity Attack as a Reaction. 
If the Goblin survives, then it continues its turn, moving away as it desires.

Answer (score 7):

The creature that was interrupted:

> If the reaction interrupts **another creature**’s turn, ***that* creature** can continue its turn right after the reaction.

This sentence structure explicitly connects the two mentions of "creature" so that they mean the same creature.